# Auxilio com TRIGGER MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, trigger

Preciso montar uma *trigger* que antes de deletar um usuário ela verifique se existem ocorrências vinculadas ao usuário em questão, e se existir, não permitir o delete, porém nunca trabalhei com *Triggers*.

Alguém pode me auxiliar?

Possuo a tabela `usuario` e a `ocorrencias` onde o campo `ocorrencias.responsavel` referencia o `ID` do usuário.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você não precisa de uma `trigger`. Só é necessário que você crie uma `foreign key` da coluna e determine que não é possível deletar caso haja um filho:

```
ALTER TABLE ocorrencias
    ADD CONSTRAINT frk_ocorrencias_usuario
    FOREIGN KEY(responsavel)
    REFERENCES usuario(id)
    ON DELETE RESTRICT
```

> [**FOREIGN KEY Constraints**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html)
>
> The type of constraint that maintains database consistency through a foreign key relationship.

Em tradução livre:

> [**Restrições de CHAVE ESTRANGEIRA**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html)
>
> O tipo de restrição que mantém a consistência da base de dados aplicando a relação entre chaves estrangeiras.

---

Caso realmente precise realizar a verificação com `trigger` *(o que não é recomendado)* você pode fazer da seguinte forma:

```
DELIMITER $
CREATE TRIGGER trg_bd_usuario BEFORE DELETE
ON usuario
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF (SELECT 1 = 1 FROM ocorrencias WHERE responsavel = OLD.id) THEN
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
    SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Este usuário possui ocorrências e não pode ser deletado.';
  END IF;   
END$
```

Lembrando que o `SIGNAL` só funciona no `MySQL` a partir da versão `5.5`.

Comment: Quem deu o `downvote` poderia explicar o que está de errado na resposta para que eu possa corrigir?

Comment: Sorack não fui eu quem negativou, mas posso supor que é porque a pessoa pode ter pensado que a pergunta está tão pouco clara que não merecia resposta, talvez não seja contra a sua resposta e muito menos contra você, pode ser que seja uma maneira de dizer, não responda perguntas "não claras". Eu não estou afirmando, só uma teoria. Eu também ganhei um downvote em uma pergunta que recebeu votos de fechamento ontem :/, mas me parecem votos legítimos. Até mais

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento um dos problemas é o `downvote` sem explicação. Se a pessoa dissesse isso eu argumentaria que a questão pra mim está clara. Ela é simples e provavelmente não ajudará ninguém futuramente mas o que foi perguntado é bem simples. Fora que eu só respondi a questão, se alguém não concorda com a pergunta tem que votar pra fechar, não negativar quem respondeu, afinal minha resposta não está incorreta e por sinal vai além da pergunta. Segundo a página de "vote down": `...Ou uma resposta que é clara e talvez perigosamente incorreta.` caso contrário tem outras abordagens.

Comment: Enfim, espero que a pessoa que fez isso leia atentamente a parte de [Privilégios - Votar Contra](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down) já que o voto negativo incorreto é prejudicial ao funcionamento do site.

Comment: Bom dia, eu precisava fazer via trigger pois é um pré-requisito, tem como?

Comment: @JeffersonKist adicionei o exemplo com `trigger`

Comment: Obrigado amigo, resolveu meu problema =).